# Create Button that allows to select a part

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

how to make a button (Refer to picture eg. Frame) that when clicked will open a diaglog box that will allow me to select a part from a list in Sheet2 and after selecting the part from the diaglog box will populate the Part picker in the google sheet

[part picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHPEN.png)

Sheet 2 fields

Description Part    SKU Model   Part    Price   Color   Qauntity
Frame
Frame
Frame
Frame
Frame
Gear
Gear
Gear
Gear

Diaglog box for the part picker

```
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Partpicker')
      .setWidth(800)
      .setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Part Picker');
}
```

PartPicker.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
        **"How to display Sheet2 by Description selected here"**  

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the project dummy file 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GeRBRYMuoIOntmcYIdOtZuYpnU2Vxw7b7KzJVEwOcl4/edit#gid=509390272

Comment: Use `google.script.run` to `getValues()` and create a table from it. See Html best practices in [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Can you share the project to reproduce the issue? Also, have you implemented @TheMaster comment? If so please share the outcome.

Comment: Here is the project file -  essentially i want to insert a button that will open a dialog box what will allow me to select a parts from a dependend list https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GeRBRYMuoIOntmcYIdOtZuYpnU2Vxw7b7KzJVEwOcl4/edit#gid=509390272

Comment: @TheMaster im only learning at the moment and only familiar in manipulating the cells, im not yet familiar how to pass or get values from the dialog boxes

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If not can you clarify the question please?